# One-to-many query with lookup and link tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

My current test revolves around a hypothetical database consisting of a `Person` table which is predominantly populated with Ids from lookup tables.

I also have a `Training` table that also has an `Id` link to a `Course` table.
I have created a link table called `PersonTraining` that links the `Person` and `Training` tables through their respective Ids. [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z56CU.png)

My objective is a query that will return the results table.

I can create a query that returns the `Person` table with all the id’s replaced with their respective lookup table values. In essence this is the below and trust this is the correct method?

```
Select 
    PersonId, Name, [DepartmentTable].Department, [PayTable].Pay 
From 
    [PersonTable]
Left Join 
    [DepartmentTable] on [PersonTable].DepartmentId = [DepartmentTable]. DepartmentIdLeft 
Join 
    [PayTable] on [PersonTable]. PayId = [PayTable]. PayId
```

I am unable however to figure out how to return this along with the course names they have attended.

[image: See Results Image]

Any assistance would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely clear what the difference between "training" and "course" is ... are those two separate tables? With a 1:1 relationship?

But assuming you want to extend your existing query to also include the m:n link from `Person` to `Training` - try this:

```
Select 
    p.PersonId, p.Name, d.Department, pay.Pay,
    c.CourseName
From 
    dbo.[PersonTable] p
Left Outer Join 
    dbo.[DepartmentTable] d on p.DepartmentId = d.DepartmentId
Inner Join 
    dbo.[PayTable] pay on p.PayId = pay.PayId
-- do a left join to the association table - not every person will have a training
Left Outer Join 
    dbo.PersonTrainingTable pt on p.PersonId = pt.PersonId
-- do a left join to the training table
Left Outer Join 
    dbo.TrainingTable t on pt.TrainingId = t.TrainingId
Left Outer Join
    dbo.CourseTable c on t.CourseId = c.CourseId
```

**Updated:** added the `CourseTable` and made sure to use the names you have (but *why* are you calling each table `AbcTable` - it's clear that it's a table, that suffix adds no additional value at all ..)

Comment: Thank you for your response and you questioning the difference between "Training" and "Course" Tables as it made me realise there was an error which I have now corrected within the image. I have attempted your suggested solution and I regret it did not work but that is probably due to my original error.

Comment: Much appreciated this works with one minor amendment Line 7 "d.DepartmentIdLeft" I believe should read "d.DepartmentId"